# Does Apple allow developers to use XOR hash to secure game assets?

Tags: encryption, app-store, xor

I have developed a game for submission to the Apple Appstore.  However, before submission, I am told that applications that contain encryption are not allowed.  My game contains a XOR hash to secure the game assets so average users cannot easily extract them by opening the IPA file.  Is a XOR hash considered encryption?  Is a XOR hash allowed on the Apple Appstore?

Answer (score 0):

1. iOS apps can use encryption.
2. A hash is not encryption, it is one-way and the original input can not be recovered.
3. Instead of an "XOR hash" consider a standard cryptographic hash such as SHA-512. Or does "XOR hash" mean some form of XOR encryption?
4. The flaw is that the encryption key must be in the app. Not a large flaw if it is hard-coded in the app code since the IPA can not be decrypted except by exection so the skill/effort is high.